# HTTPS redirection with kubernetes l4 load balancer

Tags: django, redirect, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

My application does not need to respond to http requests, except to redirect them to https, but I'm having trouble configuring it for that.  I have Django, behind Guincorn, behind a Google Cloud level 4 load balancer (set up through kubernetes).  I'm not using nginx, because the static files are served through google cloud storage buckets so it seemed to add unnecessary complexity (is there a reason this is wrong?)

When I configure guincorn for https, it doesn't respond to http requests (ok).  The first idea I had was to forward port 80 and 443 through the load balancer and then let django/guincorn take care of redirection, but I can't get guincorn to serve both http and https at the same time, even when I tried exposing two ports:

```
gunicorn --threads 2 -b :8000 --keyfile=key.txt --certfile=cert.txt myapp.wsgi
```

The load balancer config is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: xxx
  labels:
    name: xxx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 443
    name: https
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    name: app
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

It is possible to changes this so that gunicorn will also answer https requests? (the Django config is setup not to redirect http requests).
Or have I gone about this completely wrong?  Should I be trying to perform the redirection at the load balancer itself?

Answer (score 0):

The advice from kubernetes is to use an ingress controller with behind that (in this case) an nginx to redirect http to https.

What this does is:
 - The nginx looks at the http_forwarded_for and redirects to https if that is not set correctly.
 - The ingress will actually terminate the https for you so that your applications do not have to do this.

Look at https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx for detailed examples.